# upload image with url of the image using nodejs gridjs,multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ejs, multer

hey im trying to upload an image/video via the link (https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/536/354.jpg) of the image to my mongodb,
i used to work with choose file option , but now i want to change the process to be made by image or video url,
 i have tried to change the choose file to text input , but its not working , how can i solve this problem

didnt found any information about uploading by link only for choose file .

this is the route and the storage structure:

```
    // Create storage engine
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: 'uploads'
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});
const upload = multer({ storage });
// @route POST /upload
// @desc  Uploads file to DB
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  // res.json({ file: req.file });
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

this is the view i made:
the choose file is commnted out

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    img {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Mongo File Uploads</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
        <h1 class="text-center display-4 my-4">Mongo File Uploads</h1>
        <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="custom-file mb-3">
            <input type="text" name="file" id="file" >
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        </form>
        <hr>
        <% if(files){ %>
          <% files.forEach(function(file) { %>
            <div class="card card-body mb-3">
              <% if(file.isImage) { %>
                <img src="image/<%= file.filename %>" alt="">
                <% } else { %>
                  <%= file.filename %>
                    <% } %>
                      <form method="POST" action="/files/<%= file._id %>?_method=DELETE">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block mt-4">Delete</button>
                      </form>
            </div>
            <% }) %>
              <% } else { %>
                <p>No files to show</p>
                <% } %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

thanks advice to all the helpers !

Comment: what error are you getting when you used input type "file"?

Comment: i didnt get any error , the image just not uploading to the mongodb

Comment: @warmachine im not using input:file , i used to do it to choose image from my pc ,
now i want to upload an image from image url to the mongodb